# Java use of AVL tree for frequency of strings problem

Tags: java, string, tree, avl-tree

I am exploring a problem where I have to keep track of the number of strings that contains a certain substring. I was wondering how do I use an AVL tree to solve it.

Here is the problem/question: https://open.kattis.com/problems/nicknames

Comment: Are you saying that you **have** to use [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) to solve the exercise? Also, it's not clear to me from the question whether the the list of names and the list of nicknames are both sorted (alphabetically).

Comment: @Abra Yes it is mandatory to use an AVL tree to solve. The question doesn't state that but based on the input, looks like it's in alphabetical order. Any insights to using AVL tree to solve this?